# Associating multiple values to a single key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I am making a program, a part of which should have the following output.

```
dic_friends={'Ron' :['soccer' , 'tennis' ], 
             'Scott' :['swimming' , skiing',' tennis' ], 
             'Amanda' :[' cricket' , 'badminton' , 'hockey' ]}

places_dic={ 'New York' : [ 'Pool' ,' tennis' ], 
             'Florida' : ['swimming', 'hockey' , 'soccer' ] : 
             'Washington' :[ 'Cricket' , 'pool', 'soccer' , 'tennis' ,' badminton' ]}
```

Basically, I want to assign multiple values (in form of a list) to a key, in python. And I am unable to do that. 
I want the help with the syntax. So can you please provide me with the correct syntax to get the above mentioned output? 
EDIT 
Thanks to all for ur help. But I guess my question is not clear enough. The above mentioned format should be the output of the program.
I need the syntax/code of how I can take the input from the user & the syntax to how I can display the out in the above format 
PLEASE HELP!!

IN THE HOPE OF AN EARLY AND POSITIVE RESPONSE FROM YOUR SIDE.

Comment: Please format your post : [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. ... `And I am unable to do that.`  - what is going wrong?

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors in your code: a missing quote and a colon instead of a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open the quote on Scott's skiing. This should work:

```
    dic_friends={'Ron' :['soccer' , 'tennis' ], 'Scott' :['swimming' , 'skiing',' tennis' ], 'Amanda' :[' cricket' , 'badminton' , 'hockey' ]}
```

On the next one:

```
    places_dic={ 'New York' : [ 'Pool' ,' tennis' ], 
         'Florida' : ['swimming', 'hockey' , 'soccer' ], 
         'Washington' :[ 'Cricket' , 'pool', 'soccer' , 'tennis' ,' badminton' ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in python 3.6 but the underlying concept should apply if you have a dictionary -

```
a_dict={1:['a','b','c'],2:['w','z']}
```

then to append values to a key, all you need to do is -

```
a_dict[1].append('value')
```

You can add a condition to do this before you add a value-

```
if a in a_dict.keys():  
    a_dict[a].append(value)
else:  
    a_dict['a'] = ['value']
```

I hope this helps.